# How to receive HTML response from an API and bind it to view template in Angular 7.

Tags: angular

my API call's response is HTML document and I need to bind the html response to my angular's template. I tried it using below observable code and no luck. Any help please.

**Service method:**

```
getResults(): Observable<string> {
     return this.http.get<any>('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular');
  }
```

**Subscribe in the component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService.getResults()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
    },
    error => console.log('Error from backend API', +error));
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well?

Comment: I haven't coded the HTML binding yet. Firstly I am trying to make sure the service part is correct.

Comment: Can you add more info? Exactly what is not working?

Comment: Also note, if you try to fetch any link like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular`, you might get CORS errors. Try to load any local file and check if you are getting any error.

Comment: You're right Gowtham, I am getting CORS error on API call. But the same call is working well on loading a local JSON file.


`Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
app.component.ts:29 Error from backend API NaN`

Comment: Ok, as mentioned in my previous comment, its being blocked because of CORS, so try to load a local file. Also please add these errors in question, so you can get answers more quickly.

Answer (score 4):

If I understend the problem correctly in response you get html code for example:

```
<div>Some text</div>
```

And you want to add that inside of your template.? So first of all you have to modify your get call. Get, by default, expect the json in response.
What you have to do is this:

```
getResults(): Observable<string> {
     return this.http.get<string>('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular',{responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

and second in the template:

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
```

and then in the subscriber

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService.getResults()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.innerHtml = data;
    },
    error => console.log('Error from backend API', +error));
  }
```

---

if this is a **CORS** problem you have to set the proxy if you work in local environment. Go and create proxy.conf.json.

```
{
  "/questions/tagged/angular": {
    "target": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

change the url:

```
getResults(): Observable<string> {
     return this.http.get<any>('/questions/tagged/angular');
  }
```

and the run your app with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Comment: @szybicki and Gowtham, I did as you suggested above. Getting below two issues:

1. on the below statement, the `{responseType: 'text"}` throws an error like Type **'"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.ts(2322)**

`getResults(): Observable<string> {
     return this.http.get<string>('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular',{responseType: 'text'});
  }`


Secondly, GET http://localhost:4200/questions/tagged/angular 500 (Domain Not Found)

Comment: fyi - This below call works well:

`this.http.get('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS', {responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });;`

Answer (score 0):

What Cors means that, if you try to access say `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular`, you are only allowed to make that request only when window URL is `https://stackoverflow.com`. The URL you see in your browser while making a request is called **origin**. When you request from localhost, it will get blocked, since **localhost** and **https://stackoverflow.com** are different. And this is controlled by a response header called `access-control-allow-origin`. This will be set by that particular site which you are visiting. We cannot change this. You can read more about this at [MDN - CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

So for development purpose you can setup a simple local server to return a html file. Or try accessing a site, which doesnt set `access-control-allow-origin` flag.

For example, Mozilla site, allows access from all, hence if you try changing from [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS it will work.

You can check whether an site allows cross access in network tab. See the below pic. If its * all is allowed, or only the mentioned urls will be allowed.

[image: access-control-allow-origin]

Also note, angular by default considers all request to be `json`. If you are reading other types such as `html`, you need to specify that using `{responseType: 'text'}` as second argument.

```
this.http.get('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS', {responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });;
```

See [Stackblitz live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqn3ee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)